# Use Sentry's Raven JS to collect all HTTP errors

Tags: javascript, logging, sentry, raven

I have setup a Sentry application to collect HTTP / JS errors that can occur on the client side. However, it seems that when I try to make some 400 HTTP requests, Sentry failed to capture the request accordingly.

Is it the default behavior of Sentry, or if something missing in my code (below)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <title>Hi there</title>
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.ravenjs.com/2.1.1/raven.min.js"></script>
            <script>Raven.config('http://xxx@xxx.xxxxx.com/4').install();</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello the world :-)
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.get("http://somehttp400url.com/");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49462553/sentry-not-logging-the-404-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ajaxError` handler ( https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/ ):

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function( event, request, settings ) {
  Raven.captureException(new Error(JSON.stringify(request)));
});
```

Comment: Great! it works. Thanks. Btw, if we have a script or style tag pointing to an invalid file (which will return 404), is it possible to be collected by Sentry as well?

Comment: No, there's actually no way to get that information automatically. You could try to do it this way:

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>if (!window.jQuery) Raven.captureMessage('missing jQuery!');</script>

Comment: @HoangHUA there is a better way than explicitly checking each lib. You can use onerror:
`<link href="some.bad.url.com/" onerror="trackFailure('failed to get X')" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`
and:
`function trackFailure(msg) { Raven.captureException(msg) }`

Answer (score 2):

Sentry [docs on function wrapping](https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/javascript/tips/#jquery-ajax-error-reporting) will be the most canonical source on this, but effectively tell you to do what Bob says. :)

Answer (score 1):

I found this to work best combining all available information into additional data field:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
  var new_obj= Object.assign({},jqXHR, ajaxSettings);
  Raven.captureMessage(thrownError || jqXHR.statusText, {
        extra: new_obj
  });
});
```